# Xamarin.IOS go back from CNContactViewController.FromContact to Application

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have an application written with Xamarin for IOS and Android where I have a list of contacts and when I click on one of them I want to open the according contact in the addressbook of the phone. I have an interface for that implement the method on IOS that way:

```
private void ShowContactDialog(string addressbookId, bool isEdit = false)
    {
        var contact = new AddressBookService().GetCnContactById(addressbookId);
        var view = CNContactViewController.FromContact(contact);
        view.Editing = isEdit;

        DisplayView(view);
    }

    private static void DisplayView(CNContactViewController view)
    {
        var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
        var vc = window.RootViewController;
        while (vc.PresentedViewController != null)
        {
            vc = vc.PresentedViewController;
        }

        if (vc is UINavigationController navController)
        {
            vc = navController.ViewControllers.Last();
        }
        vc.PresentViewController(new UINavigationController(view), true, null);
    }
```

That works so far as it opens the contact:

[image]

The issue now is, that there is just an edit button, but now Done, cancel or back button. Therefore I have to kill the whole application and start it again to come back.

Is there a way to add a extra button similar to the edit button to dismiss the dialog again?

EDIT: I adjusted the code as suggested in the comments by Kevin Li.

```
        private void ShowContactDialog(string addressbookId, bool isEdit = false)
    {
        var contact = new AddressBookService().GetCnContactById(addressbookId);
        var view = CNContactViewController.FromContact(contact);
        view.Editing = isEdit;

        GetCurrentViewController().NavigationController.PushViewController(view, true);
    }

    private static UIViewController GetCurrentViewController()
    {
        var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
        var vc = window.RootViewController;
        while (vc.PresentedViewController != null)
        {
            vc = vc.PresentedViewController;
        }

        if (vc is UINavigationController navController)
        {
            vc = navController.ViewControllers.Last();
        }
        return vc;

    }
```

Now it is shown within the Tabs:

[image]

Unfortunately is the back button not displayed as well. 
I tried to make a new UINavigationController, but that didn't change anything.

EDIT2: 
I adjusted the way the tabs are created another time. My MainViewController looks like that:

```
[MvxRootPresentation(WrapInNavigationController = true)]
public class MainViewController : MvxTabBarViewController<MainViewModel>
{
    private bool constructed;
    private bool firstTimePresented = true;

    public MainViewController()
    {
        constructed = true;

        // need this additional call to ViewDidLoad because UIkit creates the view before the C# hierarchy has been constructed
        ViewDidLoad();
    }

    public override async void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

        if (firstTimePresented)
        {
            // Initialize the tabs
            firstTimePresented = false;
            await ViewModel.GoToContactListCommand.ExecuteAsync();
            await ViewModel.GoToBirthdayListCommand.ExecuteAsync();
            await ViewModel.GoToProfileListCommand.ExecuteAsync();
            await ViewModel.GoToSettingsCommand.ExecuteAsync();
        }
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        if (!constructed)
            return;

        base.ViewDidLoad();

        Title = "Connect Update";
        EdgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;
        View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
    }
}
```

On each View who shall be a tab has to be this Attribute:

```
[MvxTabPresentation(TabIconName = "IconCake", TabName = "Birthdays")]
    public partial class BirthdayView : MvxViewController<BirthdayViewModel>
```

The code for opening the contact is the same as above. Now it makes a new View without the tabs but with the back button, exactly as wished :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **The issue now is, that there is just an edit button, but now Done, cancel or back button.**

It is because the value of `isEdit` at `view.Editing = isEdit;` is `false`. So, when you present the CNContactViewController, there's only an **Edit** button. When you click the `Edit` button, it will change to the editing mode and the Cancel and Done buttons will appear.

Or you can set the value of `isEdit` to `true`, then the **Cancel** and **Done** buttons will show when the CNContactViewController presents.

> **Therefore I have to kill the whole application and start it again to come back.**
>
> **Is there a way to add a extra button similar to the edit button to dismiss the dialog again?**

You don't have to kill and restart the app to dismiss the dialog. You can just implement the `DidComplete` in the delegate: `CNContactViewControllerDelegate` to dismiss the dialog when user finishes editing the contact and click the **Done** button or cancel it with clicking the **Cancel** button.

Here's the related code snippet:

```
var view = CNContactViewController.FromContact(contact);
view.Delegate = new MyCNConatactViewControllerDelegate();

public class MyCNConatactViewControllerDelegate : CNContactViewControllerDelegate
{
    public override void DidComplete(CNContactViewController viewController, Contacts.CNContact contact)
    {
        viewController.NavigationController.DismissViewController(true, null);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

**To show the Back button in the CNContactViewController**:

Make sure the UI hierarchy like this: Navigation->Viewcontroller(Page)->CNContactViewController. Then change the method from `Present` to `Push` to show the CNContactViewController, like this:

`this.NavigationController.PushViewController(view, true);`

Comment: The thing is that I only want to show the contact. In the addressbook, not edit it. From what you see I have to adjust that to do it in another way.

Comment: Oh, I see. What's your UI hierarchy. If it looks like this: Viewcontroller(Page)->CNContactViewController, you could change it to Navigation->Viewcontroller(Page)->CNContactViewController. Then change the `PresentViewController` related code to `this.NavigationController.PushViewController(view, true);`

Comment: Then the ViewController(Page) is the rootViewController of the Navigation. And the CNContactViewController will show the back button. Of course, you have to change the `Present` to `Push`.

Comment: Ah, I see. That worked so far. But I have a bottom tabbar and here it doesn't show the back button for any of the navigations I do within that. So I have to see how I can fix that. But that is another issue I guess. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: All right, I adjusted my code accordingly to this example: https://github.com/rrispoli/SampleTabs. Now in general the navigation works with the back buttons. Unfortunately not for contact dialog.  I updated my original post. Any idea? =(

Comment: I figured it out. The original post has the whole solution in the edits. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Ah, glad to hear that : ). If my answer is helpful, could you please give me a vote and accept it?